# Call custom methods from a Froala custom button

Tags: angular, froala

I am developing an Angular 7 app and in this app I am using the WYSIWYG editor library called Froala.

I have added a custom button to the toolbar and now I want to call a method in the same class the user clicks on this button (to open up a custom modal). I use the code below but I get an error saying it does not find the openPictureModal method.

```
$.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('imagePicker', {NAME: 'info'});
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('imagePicker', {
      title: 'Image picker',
      focus: false,
      undo: false,
      refreshAfterCallback: false,
      callback: function (data) {
        this.openPictureModal();
      }
    });
```

**I get this error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.openPictureModal is not a function
```

This is my modal method:

```
openPictureModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PictureManageComponent, { size: 'lg' });
          modalRef.componentInstance.formFinished.subscribe(($event) => {
            modalRef.close();
          });
  }
```

How can I call custom methods in the same class from a custom button?

Comment: Define the callback as an arrow function: `callback: (data) => { this.openPictureModal(); }`.

Comment: Thanks, in a way it works but the method I call (a call to open a modal) does not fire until I click the editor area. Very strange. It does not seem to call the method directly. I have updated my question with the method code.

Comment: I think it´s because when the modal is supposed to open the editor loses focus. That is why it works when I click on the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. The first one, which is very common, is that `this` is lost inside of the callback. Defining the callback as an arrow function should take care of that problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback?rq=1) for more details.

The second issue is more subtle. The callback, being a jQuery event handler, is probably called outside of the Angular zone. As a consequence, it does not trigger change detection. You can wrap the callback code in `NgZone.run()` to solve that problem.

The resulting code would be something like this:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

...

initializeFroala() {
  $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('imagePicker', {NAME: 'info'});
  $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('imagePicker', {
    title: 'Image picker',
    focus: false,
    undo: false,
    refreshAfterCallback: false,
    callback: (data) => {            // Define the callback as arrow function
      this.ngZone.run(() => {        // Run the callback code in Angular zone
        this.openPictureModal();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. No delay, no strange behaviour! Now I only need to be able to insert at the exact right place (user selection). Problem is keeping the selection when the modal opens.